# How to pronounce "Gradle"?

Tags: pronunciation

We use a building tool named [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) in our project, but we don't know how to pronounce the `a` in it.

Someone speaks it like `a` in `cake`, but someone speaks it like `a` in `bad`.

How may we determine the correct pronunciation of this unique proper name, which does not appear in dictionaries?

Comment: It's *a* in cake. You might have searched this on the net before you ask it here.

Comment: @MaulikV Really? This is not a common word, which online dictionary did you find it in?

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Unfortunately this question is off-topic because single word pronunciation questions can be easily answered by any standard online or paper-based dictionary. If you're having *specific* problems understanding what the dictionary is telling you, please feel free to add what the dictionary says and why you don't understand it, and I'll reopen the question

Comment: @Matt None of my dictionaries have an entry for *gradle*.

Comment: @Matt, before asking this question, I've done a lot of searchs, but no answer

Comment: The word, gradle, is not in any online dictionary. It's the name of a computer tool, it is therefore a proper noun. In fact it's spelt with a capital letter. Intuition tells me that it should be pronounced as     /'ɡreɪdl̩/ like cradle but with a "g".

Comment: For uncommon brand names like *gradle*, the only way to know for sure what how it is pronounced is to *ask the people that own it*. The question is excessively localized, and cannot be answered by a native speaker in an authoritative way, and hence is not (IMO) a good fit for ELL. The best the you can do here is to look up similar words in a dictionary (such as *ladle*) and try pronouncing the words similarly.

Comment: @Gilles You are right but then there are some online tools based on common rules of pronunciation in English. http://www.pronouncehow.com/english/gradle_pronunciation. The OP asks about the pronunciation and not the meaning.

Comment: @MaulikV This site doesn't have the pronunciation, only a recording. I'm also not confident in a site that seems to include the pronunciation of non-words: what is their pronunciation based on?

Comment: Ensuing meta discussion: [Are questions about pronunciation of brand-names, trademarks and character names and so on acceptable?](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/882/are-questions-about-pronunciation-of-brand-names-trademarks-and-character-names)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The pronunciations of proper names are notoriously unpredictable.

- Old placenames and family names may preserve old spellings set in writing before natural evolution changed the pronunciation—*Cholmondely*, for instance, which is pronounced *chumly*.
- Names may undergo all sorts of changes in pronunciation or spelling as people or their names migrate into different speech communities—my own family name, for instance, is spelled with {ey} instead of its original {eu} because a US customs official was confused by the German dialect pronunciation of {eu} as /aɪ/.
- New coinages, particularly of company or product names, may be driven by typographic rather than linguistic considerations—*iPod*, for instance, or *dBase*.

So where do you turn to learn the “correct” pronunciation?

1. You could follow the usage of knowledgeable users ... But in your case, unfortunately, these users are not consistent.
2. You could assume that the spelling follows ordinary patterns. This is, to be sure, a very unreliable guide. But a little poking around in rhyming dictionaries turns up the fact that English words in *-adle*—*cradle*, *ladle*—are pronounced with a ‘long a’, /eɪ/, while words with a ‘short a’, /æ/, are spelled with a doubled consonant: *addle*, *saddle*.
3. Your best source is “the horse’s mouth” (if you don’t know this expression, which means ‘the authoritative source’, it is explained [here](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/336400.html)). In the end, the pronunciation of a name is determined by the person or entity who bears it. I find nothing explicitly about pronunciation on Gradle's own website, http://www.gradle.org; but I **do** find mention of  a presentation “Rocking the Gradle”, which is very suggestive. We speak of ‘rocking’ a baby’s cradle, and the pun would be much less effective if *Gradle* and *cradle* didn’t rhyme.

   I also find that the originator of the system and the organization is named Hans Dockter, who we may presume is the “horse”. Searching on that name  on YouTube I find a video interview with Herr Dockter [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXoIzzcJr80)—and in it he consistently pronounces the name to rhyme with *cradle* and *ladle*.

---

Just as a by-the-way: the word *gradle* (no capital) is in fact recorded in English, though I have found it in no dictionaries. It appears three times in Sean O’Casey’s play *Juno and the Paycock*, where it represents a Dublin working-class elision of the quantifier *great deal*—“I’m sorry to say there’s a gradle wrong with her.”

Comment: I thought another possible way might be to shove the word through the text-to-speech feature in Windows. I have several voices installed besides [Microsoft "Sam"](http://softadvice.informer.com/Microsoft_Sam_Text_To_Speech.html), but I'm astonished to find they *all* pronounce "gradle" as "graddle".

Comment: To be even more precise, here is the first spot where he pronounces gradle: https://youtu.be/XXoIzzcJr80?t=50